# Purchasing Chromebook for Ubuntu installation and programming

Tags: laptop, linux, chromebook

I'm thinking of buying a new laptop. I want something **cheap** and **light** with a **good battery life**. I've owned **Chromebooks** in the past, and found they suited my needs then very well. However, since then I've taken up **programming**, both as a hobby and a career, and I've always found programming in any OS other than **Linux** to be a prohibitively painful experience.

I've heard encouraging stories about people installing Ubuntu on Chromebooks, and that strategy seems like it would suit my present needs perfectly, but I have some questions:

- Is installing Ubuntu still **relatively straightforward** on recently-manufactured Chromebooks? Or is this something Google have cracked down on?
- **How well does Ubuntu run on a Chromebook?** I'll be using it almost exclusively for browsing the web, writing code and running a few relatively low-intensity Python scripts. How might it compare to ChromeOS?
- Can I get a **cheaper** Linux laptop, of comparable quality to a Chromebook, by looking elsewhere?

Answer (score 2):

The Ubuntu site itself has made a [guide](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-on-chromebook#1-overview) on how to install Ubuntu on a Chromebook so there shouldn't be much problems in that regard

Ubuntu would run fairly well for your needs assuming the Chromebook has decent specs and enough RAM

This would entirely depend on the deals you get and I will not be able to answer that though you would probably find a better deal on Linux laptops since there would not be any cost for licensing the OS.

Comment: Google seems to be doing below-0 licensing cost since you're the product.